# Use Bulk Insert or use default data in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

Need help knowing if the following is possible.

I am uploading supplies for new teachers.  When a teacher is new, they can either use default supplies already in our system or they can send in a .csv file for custom supplies.

I have a script written to upload the .csv file and insert it into the DB.  And I have a script for just inserting records for the new teacher if they are using our default values.  I am wondering if these 2 scripts can be combined.

So, if the file exists in my @FPath, I would like to upload it into my #T table.  If it doesn't exist, I want to insert the default values into my temp #T table.

I am familiar with IF THEN ELSE and I'm thinking that's what I'd use, but I don't know how to tell it to check if a file exists.

Here's what I have currently:

DECLARE
    @Query          Varchar(2000),
    @TeacherKey     Varchar(10)  = 1234,
    @FPath          Varchar(100) = 'FilePath_1234.csv'

CREATE TABLE #T ( 
    SupplyName      Varchar(50),
    PkgQuantity     Varchar(5),
    Price           Varchar(9))

-- If file exists, I want to upload it (IF @FPath exists THEN)

SELECT @Query = '
BULK INSERT #T 
   FROM  ''' + @FPath + '''
   WITH
     (FIELDTERMINATOR ='','',
        ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
        FIRSTROW = 2
      )'
EXEC (@Query)

-- Otherwise I will use default values already in the DB (ELSE)

INSERT #T ( 
    SupplyName,
    PkgQuantity,
    Price)
SELECT SupplyName, PkgQty, Price
    FROM Supply
WHERE TeacherKey = 1111

Any help or guidance is much appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to document I figured this out.  I did it using xp_fileexist.

```
DECLARE 
@Query Varchar(2000), 
@TeacherKey Varchar(10) = 1234, 
@FPath Varchar(100) = 'FilePath_1234.csv',
@IsExists Int

CREATE TABLE #T 
(SupplyName Varchar(50), PkgQuantity Varchar(5), Price Varchar(9))

EXEC xp_fileexist @FPath, @IsExists OUTPUT

IF @IsExists = 1 

BEGIN
SELECT @Query = ' 
BULK INSERT #T 
   FROM ''' + @FPath + ''' 
   WITH 
      (FIELDTERMINATOR ='','', 
      ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', 
      FIRSTROW = 2 
   )' 
EXEC (@Query)
END

ELSE

INSERT #T ( SupplyName, PkgQuantity, Price) 
SELECT SupplyName, PkgQty, Price  
FROM Supply WHERE TeacherKey = 1111
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically for interacting with the file system of the SQL Server instance's host server you want to utilize the xp_* stored procedures in the master system DB.

```
xp_fileexist 'C:/yourdestination'
```

Is probably the quickest method you could use to qualify an IF/THEN condition switch.